# Inferring the type of an object's property

Tags: typescript, generics

I have the following type:

```
type ErrorMessageMapping<T> =
    T extends object ?
        { [P in keyof T]: ErrorMessageMapping<T[P]> }
        : T extends string ?
            Record<T, string>
            : never;
```

Currently, it gives all properties a type of `string`. Is there a way to infer the type, based on the value?

Here is how I use it:

```
enum Errors {
  WrongName = 'wrong_name',
  DuplicateName = 'duplicate_name'
}

const duplicateNameErrorMessage = () => {
  return {
    title: 'Duplicate name',
    description: 'Please choose another.'
  }
}

const erors: ErrorMessageMapping<Errors> = {
  wrong_name: 'The name is wrong.',
  duplicate_name: duplicateNameErrorMessage() // error, must be string
}
```

I know the issue is with `Record<T, string>` from the definition of `ErrorMessageMapping` but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Here is how I use this in real life:

```
type ErrorMessageMapping<T> =
    T extends object ?
        { [P in keyof T]: ErrorMessageMapping<T[P]> }
        : T extends string ?
            Record<T, string>
            : never;

type Result<T> = {
    [Prop in keyof T as `${Uncapitalize<string & Prop>}ErrorMessage`]?: string;
};

export function useFieldValidationMessage<
    T extends Record<string, string | undefined>
>(
    fieldError: Optional<T>,
    errorMessageMapping: ErrorMessageMapping<T>,
): Result<ErrorMessageMapping<T>> {
    const errorMessages = useMemo<Result<ErrorMessageMapping<T>>>(() => {
        if (!fieldError) {
            return {};
        }

        return Object.entries(fieldError).reduce<Result<ErrorMessageMapping<T>>>(
            (prev, [field, error]) => {
                if (!field || !error) {
                    return prev;
                }

                const mapping = errorMessageMapping[field];
                if (mapping === undefined) {
                    return prev;
                }

                return {
                    ...prev,
                    [`${field}ErrorMessage`]: mapping[error],
                };
            },
            {},
        );
    }, [fieldError, errorMessageMapping]);

    return errorMessages;
}


const errors: Record<string, Errors> = {
  name: 'duplicate_value'
}

const { nameErrorMessage } = useFieldValidationMessage(errors, {
        name: {
            duplicate_value: 'duplicate name,
            missing_required_field: 'missing field',
        }
    });
```

Comment: If you remove the type from `erors` (sic), then `type X = typeof erors` will correctly be inferred. Unclear what you're trying to achieve here.

Comment: You probably want something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/N718qW). Does this answer your question?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen I've added a real example. Hope that helps.

Comment: @TobiasS. yes, this works, but it breaks in my example.